# Send Geolocation in background service [Titanium]

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, background-process

I'm creating an app for Android and iOS with titanium which sends a new Geolocation to a server every 5 seconds for as long as the server runs. On iOS however the app stops sending those locations after a random interval. Although i myself are not completely convinced this is due to the fact that the app pauses in iOS(Since it stops randomly and not on a fixed time) i'm still eager to try and be certain.

However; i really have NO CLUE to do this whatsoever. I've created a background service in an eventListener to see what happens and it starts logging right away(I've put a console log in it for now). Nonetheless, my geolocation is still ticking normally aswell.

Now, could someone please give me some pointers on how to get through this? Do i want to stop my normal geolocation listener and let the BG service take over? Or does the BGservice keep the geolocation eventlistener in my normal code active now?

At this point i'm afraid to say that i'm pretty much desperate to get any help, haha!

Here's my geolocation handling now, along with the BGservice:

```
//Start button. listens to an eventHandler in location.js
btnStart.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if( Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled === false ) {
       GPSSaved.text = 'Your device has GPS turned off. Please turn it on.';
    } else {
        if (Titanium.Network.online) {
            GPSSaved.text = "GPS zoeken...";

            //Empty interval and text to make a clean (re)start
            clearInterval(interval);

            //Set a half second timer on the stop button appearing(So people can't double tap the buttons)
            stopTimeout = setTimeout(showStopButton, 1000);

            //Switch the textlabels and buttons from startview to stopview
            stopText.show();
            startText.hide();
            btnStart.hide();

            //Locationhandler
            location.start({ 
                action: function (e) {
                    //Ti.API.info(e.coords.longitude);
                    if (e.coords) {

                        //If the newly acquired location is not the same as the last acquired it is allowed
                        if (e.coords.longitude != lastLon && e.coords.latitude != lastLat) {

                            //set the last acquired locations+other info to their variables so they can be checked(and used)
                            lastLat = e.coords.latitude;
                            lastLon = e.coords.longitude;


                            lastKnownAltitude = e.coords.altitude;
                            lastKnownHeading = e.coords.heading;
                            lastKnownSpeed = e.coords.speed;

                            if (lastLat != 0 && lastLon != 0) {
                                setGPSholder(lastLat, lastLon, lastKnownAltitude, lastKnownHeading, lastKnownSpeed);
                            } else {
                                GPSSaved.text = 'Geen coordinaten.';
                            }
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            });

            /*
            A second interval which shows a counter to the user and makes sure a location is sent
            roughly every 5 seconds(setInterval isn't accurate though)
            A lot of counters are tracked for several reasons:
            minuteInterval:     Counter which makes sure the last location is sent after a minute if no new one is found in the meantime
            secondsLastSent:    The visual counter showing the user how long its been for the last save(Is reset to 0 after a succesful save)
            */
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                minuteInterval++;
                minuteIntervalTest++;
                secondsLastSent++;

                counterBlock.text = "De laatste locatie is " + secondsLastSent + " seconden geleden verstuurd";

                //If the counter is higher than 5 send a new coordinate. If at the same time the minuteInterval is over a minute
                //The last location is put in the array before calling the sendCoordinates
                if (counter >= 5) {
                    if (minuteInterval > 60) {
                        if (lastLat != 0 && lastLon != 0) {
                            setGPSholder(lastLat, lastLon, lastKnownAltitude, lastKnownHeading, lastKnownSpeed);
                        }
                    }
                    counter = 0;
                    sendCoordinates();
                    Ti.API.info(1);
                } else {
                    counter++;
                }

                if (minuteIntervalTest > 60) {
                    sendTestRequest();
                }
            }, 1000);


            if (Titanium.Platform.osname == 'iphone' || Titanium.Platform.osname == 'ipad') {
                //var service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({url:'send_geolocation_service.js'});
                var service;

                // Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('notification',function(e){
                // You can use this event to pick up the info of the noticiation. 
                // Also to collect the 'userInfo' property data if any was set
                //      Ti.API.info("local notification received: "+JSON.stringify(e));
                //  });
                // fired when an app resumes from suspension
                Ti.App.addEventListener('resume',function(e){
                    Ti.API.info("app is resuming from the background");
                });
                Ti.App.addEventListener('resumed',function(e){
                    Ti.API.info("app has resumed from the background");
                    // this will unregister the service if the user just opened the app
                    // is: not via the notification 'OK' button..
                    if(service!=null){
                        service.stop();
                        service.unregister();
                    }
                            Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge = null;
                });
                Ti.App.addEventListener('pause',function(e){
                    Ti.API.info("app was paused from the foreground");

                    service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({url:'send_geolocation_service.js'});
                    Ti.API.info("registered background service = "+service);

                });
            }



        } else {
            stopGPS();
            GPSSaved.text = "Geen internetverbinding.";
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see there's some counters running in an interval to decide if a geolocation should be sent every 5 seconds or every minute(If no new location since the last is found)

**tl;dr:** I want geolocations to be sent every 5 seconds but somehow iOS(iPhone 4s and 5 tested) stop sending after a random timeperiod and restart sending the moment i get the phone out of standby.

Answer (score 1):

actually background service has a limitation to stop after 10 mins so if you want to catch location when device is in background mode then you need to set mode tag in tiapp.xml file.

just refer this online doc for how it works.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-LegacyiPhonesection